# Central limit theorem, when do we know if n isn't large enough

Tags: statistics

I'm working on a statistics question, and I'm stumped on how to answer it.

Here is the question

```
According to a survey conducted by the American Bar Association, 1 in every 410
Americans is a lawyer, but 1 in every 64 residents of Washington, D.C., is a lawyer.


(a) Use the Central Limit Theorem to approximate the probability that there is at
least one lawyer in a random sample of 1500 Americans. Is n = 1500 large enough
for the approximation to work well?
```

Using the CLT, I found that the answer was approximately .95, but I don't know how to determine if the sample size is large enough for the approximation? What do you look for in this case?

Comment: The usual rule of thumb is $np\ge 10$ (or sometimes $5$) so no, the normal approximation should not be used here.

Comment: You should use a Poisson approximation instead if you want to avoid exact calculations.

Comment: The usual rule of thumb is that both $np > 5$ and $n(1-p) > 5$. Some authors use values other than 5. There are better rules of thumb, but this one is easiest to remember and works pretty well. It works best for $p$ near 1/2 and worst for probabilities far out in the tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Exact\; Binomial$: As per the Answer by @grand_chat. Let the number of lawyers
in a random sample of 1500 Americans be $X \sim Binom(1500, 1/410)$.
We seek $P(X \ge 1) = 1  - P(X = 0).$ From R, we have:

```
 1 - (409/410)^1500
 ## 0.9743447
 1 - dbinom(0, 1500, 1/410)
 ## 0.9743447
```

$Poisson\; approximation\; to\; binomial$. We must have 
$\lambda = E(X) = 1500/410 = 3.658537,$ so that
$Y \sim Pois(\lambda).$ Again, we seek $P(Y \ge 1) = 1 - P(Y=0).$

```
 1 - exp(-lam)
 ## 0.9742298
 1 - dpois(0, lam)
 ## 0.9742298
```

$Normal\; approximation$. For the binomial distribution, $\mu = np = 1500/410,$
$\sigma^2 = np(1-p) = \mu(409/410).$ Now let $W \sim Norm(\mu, \sigma).$ We seek $P(W \ge 1) = P(W > .5) = 1 - P(W < .5).$

```
 mu = 1500*(1/410);  var = mu*(409/410); sg = sqrt(var)
 1 - pnorm(.5, mu, sg)
 ## 0.9508693
```

Of course $P(W > .5)$ can be found from printed normal tables
by standardizing: $P(W > .5) = P[Z = (W - \mu)/\sigma > (.5 - \mu)/\sigma)].$ This seems to be the result you obtained. [Note: Application of the 'continuity
correction' leads us to seek $P(W \ge .5)$ instead of $P(W \ge 1).$]

$Summary\; comments.$ The Poisson approximation is very good (see figure below). Although the 'usual rule' for using the the normal approximation as given in the
comment does not hold, the normal approximation is not very good here for two additional
reasons: (a) We are dealing with a probability in the tail of
the binomial distribution, (b) we are dealing with a
skewed binomial distribution ($p$ far from 1/2). In statistical practice, normal
approximations are less frequently used nowadays than before
software was available to do exact computations.

The figure below shows the binomial distribution (black bars), its
Poisson approximation (purple dots), and the normal curve that matches the binomial mean and variance.

[image]

Comment: Larginess of $n$ has nothing to do with the quality of Poisson approximation. In fact, if $n$ was smaller, the approximation would be even better (in relative terms). What matters is that $p$ is small and we are interested in probabilities of events not far from the mean.

Comment: @A.S. Best just to refer to figure in this case. Edited summary accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the *exact* probability and compare it to the CLT approximation. The number of lawyers in a sample of $1500$ has binomial distribution with $n=1500$ and $p=1/410$, so the probability that there are **no** lawyers in your sample is
$$(1-p)^n=\left(1-\frac1{410}\right)^{1500}.$$
Subtract this number from $1$ to get the exact prob of least one lawyer in your sample.

Aside: When you did the CLT approximation, did you apply the continuity correction? (Do you know about the continuity correction?)

Comment: no what is the continuity correction?

Comment: It is an attempt to 'coordinate' the discrete binomial distribution with the continuous normal. Example: for the binomial $P(3 < X < 7) = P(4 \le X \le 6) = P(3.5 < X < 6.5).$ Of these three forms of the same expression for the binomial, the last of them leads to the best normal approximation.